# how to parse string into a date pattern using dojo

Tags: javascript, date, dojo

I have a value of `'05/17/2010'`
I would like to get it as `'May 17, 2010'` by using `dojo.date.locale`. I have tried using the `dojo.date.locale.parse` as follows:

```
x = '05/17/2010'
var x = dojo.date.locale.parse(x, {datePattern: "MM/dd/yyyy", selector: "date"});
alert(x)
```

This doesn't give me the desired date pattern.

I also tried replacing the pattern as `datePattern : "MMMM d, yyyy"` but it returns `null`.

Answer (score 5):

[dojo.date.locale.parse](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/date/locale.html#parse) takes a formatted string and returns a Javascript Date object.

```
var x = dojo.date.locale.parse('05/17/2010', {datePattern: "MM/dd/yyyy", selector: "date"});
```

When you say

```
alert(x);
```

that coerces x to a string using the Date.toString() method, which varies by browser, but will give you output like what you got -- Mon May 17 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

If you want to then format the date a special way, pass the result of your parse to dojo.date.locale.format with a specific date format:

```
var y = dojo.date.locale.format(x, {datePattern:"MMMM d, yyyy", selector: 'date'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works - though after your initial declaration of x, there is no semicolon before setting it a second time. I broke your code into three lines:

```
var x = '05/17/2010';
x = dojo.date.locale.parse(x, {datePattern: "MM/dd/yyyy", selector: "date"});
alert (x);
```

Perhaps it was just a matter of `x` not being set initially?

Comment: well...adddng a semicolon doesn't work either , since javascript is  loosely typed

Comment: And also alerting x gives me the output like this 
Mon May 17 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
but this is not what i want ... I would like to get it in May 17, 2010 format.
If I try changing the datepattern to MMMM d, yyyy, the alert gives me null . Any ideas as to what is going wrong ?

Comment: You were definitely missing a semi-colon after the first assignment of x.  That's just a syntax issue and nothing to do with typing.   You also shouldn't use var after assigning x, though the extra declaration will just be ignored.  JYelton's syntax looks correct.

Comment: It sounds like progress. Instead of getting `null` you are now getting the system default date format (as converted from a java date object). Now you just need to convert that date into the desired format string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have to first create a `Date` object and **then** you can format it, because the format function takes, as its first parameter, a `Date` object and not a string. So, if you do the following, it will work fine:

```
var x = new Date("05/17/2010");
x = dojo.date.locale.format(x, {datePattern: "MM/dd/yyyy", selector: "date"});
alert (x);
```

Comment: true, but that's the format() method. The question was about the parse() method which does take a string.